# Schwinn Collegiate 26" Front Wheel Cone Lock Nuts?

Tags: hub, front, schwinn

I'm fixing an old Schwinn Collegiate, and the front hub may or may not have been worked on before. I'm finding no cone locknuts. On one side, there is a tabbed washer. 2 ear tabs hold the cone on 2 sides, on the other side, a single ear tab that fits in the drop out to stop it from spinning. Should there be 2 washers like this?
Or, when installing the wheel, do I tighten the washer side of the hub, then adjust the non-washer side when I have the cones properly tightened, then lock down the axle nut?

[image]

---

Update:  I made another cone lockwasher out of some heavy gauge aluminum just in case there was supposed to be one on both sides, but it's not necessary.  I might add some medium loctite to the cones so they don't move so freely when removing the wheel to fix a flat (so it doesn't lose adjustment).

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is an [exploded diagram](http://www.khurramhashmi.org/khurramweb_com/gncbm_6.html) of what you are looking at:
[image]

for wheel installation you are right to say:

> tighten the washer side of the hub, then adjust the non-washer side when I have the cones properly tightened, then lock down the axle nut

The cone lock washer should be on the right side. The chain side is the right side.